# Show tabs for buffers in carbon emacs?

Tags: emacs, carbon-emacs

How can I get a tabbed interface in carbon emacs which corresponds to one-tab-per-buffer similar to Aquaemacs(http://aquamacs.org/)?

Comment: why wouldn't you just use aquamacs then?

Comment: Carbon Emacs behavior feels more close to the default Emacs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact you can take [tabbar.el from Aquaemacs](http://github.com/davidswelt/aquamacs-emacs/blob/master/aquamacs/src/site-lisp/tabbar/tabbar.el). It is not guaranteed to work with any other emacs variant but I'm lucky for Windows and Mac (Carbon and Cocoa). So it should work for you too.

You can read more at EmacsWiki .

My configuration is simply:

```
(require 'tabbar)
(tabbar-mode 1)
```

Additionally I've got some colors modifications. Please read EmacsWiki for more details. (search for tabbar)

Comment: Works ok on ubuntu 10.04, emacs-snapshot-gtk, core version: GNU Emacs 23.1.50.1